# Need help for multiagent RL with ray RLlib

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, rllib, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning, pettingzoo

i am training several agents to set optimal prices in a market environment. The agents are competing against each other. The agent that sets a lower prices gets a higher share of the demand in the market. Hypothesis: The agents will learn to collude and develop strategies to increase the prices in parallel.

When i execute the training i get the following error with a lot of different other informations:
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

The code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import gymnasium as gym
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from itertools import product
from ray.rllib.env import MultiAgentEnv
import ray
from ray.tune import registry
from ray.rllib.algorithms.ppo import PPOConfig
from ray.rllib.algorithms.dqn import DQNConfig, DQN
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box
from ray import tune
from ray import air

class PricingStrategyEnv(MultiAgentEnv):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Initialize parameters
        self.n_agents = 3
        self.c = 1  # Marginal cost for calculating profit
        self.a = 5  # perceived quality of a product. necessary for the demand function
        self.a0 = 0  # A parameter in the demand function
        self.mu = 0.25  # Price sensitivity
        self.k = 15  # Number of possible prices
        #self.tmax = 1e7  # Maximum time steps. currently not used
        self._agent_ids = [0,1,2]

        # Derived properties
        self.sdim, self.s0 = self.init_state()
        self.p_minmax = self.compute_p_competitive_monopoly()
        self.A = self.init_actions()
        self.PI = self.init_PI()

        self.action_space = Discrete(self.k)  # Discrete action space for each agent
       # self.observation_space = Box(low=np.min(self.PI), high=np.max(self.PI), shape=(self.n_agents,), dtype=np.float32)
        self.observation_space = Box(self.k, self.k)


        # Initialize state and tracking variables
        self.state = self.s0
        self.current_step = 0


    def demand(self, p):
        e = np.exp((self.a - p) / self.mu)
        d = e / (np.sum(e) + np.exp(self.a0 / self.mu))
        return d

    def foc(self, p):
        d = self.demand(p)
        zero = 1 - (p - self.c) * (1 - d) / self.mu
        return np.squeeze(zero)

    def foc_monopoly(self, p):
        d = self.demand(p)
        d1 = np.flip(d)
        p1 = np.flip(p)
        zero = 1 - (p - self.c) * (1 - d) / self.mu + (p1 - self.c) * d1 / self.mu
        return np.squeeze(zero)

    def compute_p_competitive_monopoly(self):
        p0 = np.ones((1, self.n_agents)) * 3 * self.c
        p_competitive = fsolve(self.foc, p0)
        p_monopoly = fsolve(self.foc_monopoly, p0)
        return p_competitive, p_monopoly

    def init_actions(self):
        a = np.linspace(min(self.p_minmax[0]), max(self.p_minmax[1]), self.k - 2)
        delta = a[1] - a[0]
        A = np.linspace(min(a) - delta, max(a) + delta, self.k)
        return A

    def init_state(self):
        sdim = (self.k, self.k, self.k)  # for 3 agents
        s0 = np.zeros(len(sdim)).astype(int)
        return sdim, s0

    def compute_profits(self, p):
        d = self.demand(p)
        pi = (p - self.c) * d
        return pi

    def init_PI(self):
        PI = np.zeros(self.sdim + (self.n_agents,))
        for s in product(*[range(i) for i in self.sdim]):  # Reason for adding self.k above
            p = np.asarray(self.A[np.asarray(s)])
            PI[s] = self.compute_profits(p)
        return PI

    def step(self, action_dict):
        print("Current Step:", self.current_step)
        print("Received actions:", action_dict)

        actions = []
        for agent_id, action in action_dict.items():
            actual_price = self.A[action]  # Map action index to price
            actions.append(actual_price)

        # Compute prices, demands, and profits
        prices = np.array(actions)
        demands = self.demand(prices)
        profits = self.compute_profits(prices)

        # Construct rewards. Rewards are just the same as the profit that an agent gets
        rewards = {str(agent_id): profits[agent_id] for agent_id in range(self.n_agents)}
        print("Rewards:", rewards)

        # Update past prices and rewards
        for i, price in enumerate(prices):
            self.past_prices[i].append(price)
            self.past_rewards[i].append(rewards[str(i)])

        self.current_step += 1
        done = self.current_step >= self.tmax

        # Construct observations for all agents
        observations = {}
        for agent_id in range(self.n_agents):
            observations[agent_id] = self.observe(agent_id)

        print("Observations:", observations)

        info = {}

        return observations, rewards, done, info

    def reset(self, **kwargs):
        super().reset(seed=kwargs.get('seed'))  # Pass 'seed' to Gym's reset function
        self.state = self.s0.copy()
        self.current_step = 0
        # Initialize past price and reward tracking
        self.past_prices = [[0.0] for _ in range(self.n_agents)]
        self.past_rewards = [[0.0] for _ in range(self.n_agents)]

        observations = {}
        agent_ids = list(range(self.n_agents))  # Get a list of agent IDs
        for agent_id in agent_ids:
            observations[agent_id] = self.observe(agent_id)
        
        print("Initial Observations:", observations)


        info = {}  # Create an empty info dictionary

        return observations, info


    def observe(self, agent_id):
            return {
                "own_price": self.past_prices[agent_id][-1] if self.past_prices[agent_id] else 0.0,
                "competitor_prices": [self.past_prices[i][-1] for i in range(self.n_agents) if i != agent_id],
                "last_reward": self.past_rewards[agent_id][-1] if self.past_rewards[agent_id] else 0.0
            }

    def close(self):
        pass

    def render(self, mode='human'):
        print(f"Step: {self.current_step}, State: {self.state}")


registry.register_env("PricingStrategyEnv", lambda config: PricingStrategyEnv()) 
config = (
    PPOConfig()
    .environment("PricingStrategyEnv")  
    .rollouts(num_rollout_workers=2)
    .framework("torch")
    .training(
        lr_schedule=[(0, 0.01)],  # Learning rate schedule
        clip_param=0.2,  # PPO clip parameter
        shuffle_sequences=True,  # Shuffle sequences in the batch
    )
    .evaluation(evaluation_num_workers=1)
)

algo = config.build()  # Build the algorithm

for _ in range(5):
    print(algo.train())  # Train the algorithm

algo.evaluate()  # Evaluate the algorithm
```

Before training, the environment can be tested by using the following script. I am new to MARL and RLlib, but i thought that the printed output looked ok, so i do not know what went wrong.

```
# Testing the environment
env = PricingStrategyEnv()
obs, info = env.reset()
for _ in range(3):  # Iterate through the step function three times
    action_dict = {agent_id: env.action_space.sample() for agent_id in range(env.n_agents)}
    obs, rewards, done, info = env.step(action_dict)
    if done:
        break  # Stop iterating if the episode is done
```